# CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil is not returning any results

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to display all available BLE beacons. I got some Estimote and Kontakt.io beacons with me and for some reason the below BLE scanning code does not find any of them.

I went through all the possible SO questions relating to BLE discovery and that codes is exactly as in other places.

[App source code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tefyp8jszpx8ay1/BTTest.zip?dl=0)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}


/*
 Request CBCentralManager to scan for all available services
 */
- (void) startScan
{
    NSLog(@"Start scanning");

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber  numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];

    [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
}
```

This delegate method never gets called

```
/*
 Invoked when the central discovers bt peripheral while scanning.
 */
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    NSLog(@"THIS NEVER GETS CALLED");

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iBeacon's aren't accessed as peripherals - they are beacons.  They are handled through the [Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1) framework, not the Core Bluetooth framework.

There may be vendor specific services advertised by the beacons that can be detected by Core Bluetooth.

Your code doesn't wait until the `CBCentralManager` is in the powered on state.  I made the following changes and it worked on both iOS 7.1 and iOS8 -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}

- (void) startScan
{
    NSLog(@"Start scanning");

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber  numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];

    [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];

}


- (BOOL) isLECapableHardware
{
    NSString * state = nil;

    switch ([self.manager state])
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            state = @"The platform/hardware doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            state = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            state = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            [self startScan];
            return TRUE;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        default:
            return FALSE;

    }

    NSLog(@"Central manager state: %@", state);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setMessage:state];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert show];

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: a) Beacons are BLE and they should be visible b) I don't need to interact with them, just discover.

Comment: the BLE stack in iOS specifically prevents iBeacon advertisements from being presented to `didDiscoverPeripheral`.  Kontact and Estimote beacons will advertise additional services that are used for configuration, but these services are vendor specific.

Comment: Works on iOS 7 and XCode 5 but not on iOS8 and XCode 6. Will investigate further.

Comment: It works fine on both 7.1 and 8 as long as you move the call to `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` into the case for `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`.  It isn't valid to perform any operations until you know you are in that state

Comment: :-) Yes I was writing the answer.You would think that it would be documented but its not.

Comment: I will assign you the answer, for spending the time on it! Thank you!

Comment: The programming guide says "When you create a central manager, the central manager calls the centralManagerDidUpdateState: method of its delegate object. You must implement this delegate method to ensure that Bluetooth low energy is supported and available to use on the central device" - it could be a little more explicit, but if you check the sample code it does show waiting for the power on state.  It is just in iOS 8 they have moved from a warning to a failure

Answer (score 3):

The problem was posed by the version of the OS I was testing it with. 
Let's just say this version that I was testing was 4+4 (as it is under the NDA)

Apparently that new version will abort scanning if you trigger

```
[self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

before

```
CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn is ON
```

So simply starting scanning after that state made it work for me.

```
#pragma mark - CBCentralManager delegate methods
/*
 Invoked whenever the central manager's state is updated.
 */
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    [self isLECapableHardware]? NSLog(@"YES"):NSLog(@"NO");
}


- (BOOL) isLECapableHardware
{
    NSString * state = nil;

    switch ([self.manager state])
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            state = @"The platform/hardware doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            state = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            state = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
```

//---> HERE

```
            [self startScan];


            return TRUE;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        default:
            return FALSE;

    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your code and found there was no call to startScan. Once I added that it worked for me. I added some details to the logging like this:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ %@", aPeripheral, advertisementData);

}
```

and I get this output:

```
2014-09-08 15:17:11.827 BTTest[4266:60b] New state 5
2014-09-08 15:17:11.830 BTTest[4266:60b] YES
2014-09-08 15:17:11.831 BTTest[4266:60b] Start scanning
2014-09-08 15:17:11.842 BTTest[4266:60b] CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBCentralManager: 0x17d6e5d0> is disabling duplicate filtering, but is using the default queue (main thread) for delegate events
2014-09-08 15:17:12.438 BTTest[4266:60b] per <CBPeripheral: 0x17d91220 identifier = C6E33BA0-F6E7-5830-0643-A47855AD27B9, Name = "(null)", state = disconnected> {
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 37;
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
}
2014-09-08 15:17:12.595 BTTest[4266:60b] per <CBPeripheral: 0x17d89b60 identifier = 4FF1E398-E24C-8739-A19B-9DF8A2A5493B, Name = "Flex", state = disconnected> {
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 38;
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = Flex;
    kCBAdvDataServiceData =     {
        "Device Information" = <0704>;
    };
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "ADABFB00-6E7D-4601-BDA2-BFFAA68956BA"
    );
    kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = "-6";
}
```

Comment: The problem actually was not with the code but rather with my use of iOS 8 and XCode 6 beta... I will have to investigate if there were any changes in the CoreBluetoot framework.